# How to extract comments from multiple similar structured excel files in R?

Tags: r, excel, import

I have 1000 .xlsx files with the same structure. All contain a header row (id, filling date, Item 1 to 11) and a row with values. The cell under Item 11 contains a comment in most files. How can I extract the comments from all files and combine them into a single object in R?

I managed to combine all files into a single data.frame by creating a list of the files `files <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = T)`, reading them into R using `sapply(files, read_excel)`and combining them with `bind_rows()` however, `read_excel` doesn't import the comments. I used the packages `readxl` and `dplr` for this.

I also managed to extract the comment from a single file using `xlsx_cells("file.xlsx")`  and `x[x$address=="N8", c("address", "comment")]` but I don't know how to do this with multiple files. I used the package `dplr`and `tidyxl`for this approach.

I would very much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using `purrr`:

*Edit: altered solution to output the source file for each comment and to work with files lacking such a comment, as the OP specified the comment is there in "most" files.*

```
library(tidyxl)
library(purrr)

# First, here's a list of xlsx files in the directory:
file_list <-  list.files() %>%
  .[str_detect(., ".xlsx")]
file_list
#[1] "test1.xlsx"            "test2.xlsx"            "test3 no comment.xlsx"


# Make a new tibble with two columns: 
#   file_name   is the source file we're looking at
#   comments    extracts the comments in N8, if any
tibble(file_name = file_list,
       comments = map(file_list,
                      ~ xlsx_cells(.) %>%
                        subset(address == "N8", comment))) %>%
  unnest(comments, keep_empty = TRUE)


## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  file_name             comment          
#  <chr>                 <chr>            
#1 test1.xlsx            Comment in file 1
#2 test2.xlsx            Comment in file 2
#3 test3 no comment.xlsx NA
```

Comment: thanks Jon! it works and `str_detect()` and `unnest()` solved some other issues

Comment: a little follow up: how can I, besides the comments, get the values of item 1-10 for each file in the object as well?